# Partially duplicated history when setting PS1 in .bash_profile

Tags: bash, command-history, prompt

When I set `PS1` variable in `~/.bash_profile`, it worked as configured. However, the history is somehow messed up.

When I press `Arrow Up` or `Ctrl+P` to view commands I typed, it starts to duplicate partially at some points. The scenario is displayed below(pay attention to `cd /Co` which is  the duplicated part):

[image]

Although visually duplicated, when press enter I still get the correct result in history commands.

Here's my system information:

- OS: Mac OS X 10.9.4
- Terminal: system default terminal, iTerm 2

I set `PS1` in my `.bash_profile` like this:

```bsh
PS1='${YELLOW}\u${WHITE} in ${GREEN}\w${WHITE}${YELLOW}`__git_ps1 " on 
%s"`${WHITE}\r\n${NORMAL}$ '
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put `\[` and `\]` around all escape sequences so that the line editor knows how long the prompt is.

Comment: i'm sorry i know it's ashamed to ask but i don't really understand bash stuff, i change the PS1 into

Comment: `PS1='${YELLOW}\[\u\]${WHITE} in ${GREEN}\[\w\]${WHITE}${YELLOW}`__git_ps1 " on %s"`${WHITE}\[\r\]\[\n\]${NORMAL}$ '` but it seems not wokring

Comment: @jasonslyvia no, around the ${YELLOW} and such. Back already knows how to handle \u and such.

Comment: that's very helpful, thank you so much! For future reference, the working example would be: `PS1='\[${YELLOW}\]\u\[${WHITE}\] in \[${GREEN}\]\w\[${WHITE}\]\[${YELLOW}\]`__git_ps1 " on %s"`\[${WHITE}\]\r\n\[${NORMAL}$\] '`